# How to disable backspace in jquery-inputmask if remainig number is 0?

Tags: jquery, jquery-inputmask

The following input field doesn't allow numbers start with 0, but it can be beat by typing e.g. 10 or 20 or 100 or 2390. The important thing is that the number ends with 0, and the user can delete all the numbers before getting 0.
Is there a way do avoid that? For example, when the remaining number is 0, it doesn't allow delete it.

```
$('#currency').inputmask({
  regex: '^[1-9][0-9]*([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$',
  rightAlign: false,
  placeholder: '',
  min: 1,
  inputmode: 'decimal',
  casing: function (elem) {
    if(elem == ',') return '.';
    return elem;
  }
});
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/levipadre/pen/gOQMKXW?editors=1010

Comment: I cannot find a "get value" in the documentation that works in your codepen - I tried `onUnMask: function(maskedValue, unmaskedValue) {
      console.log(maskedValue,unmaskedValue)
  },`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#currency').inputmask({
  regex: '^[1-9][0-9]*([,.][0-9]{1,2})?$',
  rightAlign: false,
  placeholder: '',
  min: 1,
  inputmode: 'decimal',
  casing: function (elem) {
    if(elem == ',') return '.';
    return elem;
  }
}).on('keydown', function (e) {
  if ($(this).val() === '0' && e.keyCode === 8) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Using key down in inputmask we can disable backspace by matching the value of the input field

Comment: Thank you, I updated the code on https://codepen.io/levipadre/pen/gOQMKXW?editors=1010 but unfortunately still not good

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).